# how to change 2 iframe tag with 1 a tag

Tags: html, css

I want to change two frames by clicking on a link and the frames are separate. And the a tag only takes one target.
[image]

Click on each food to display both the recipe and the food images

Comment: Can you want like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43579184/one-link-opens-two-iframe-targets-on-same-page

Comment: Yes, but I do not want to use programming languages. Only with HTML

Comment: It can't be done without js

Comment: Can I use bookmarks?